# What is the equivalent of a C# Static instance in C++?

Tags: c++, visual-studio-2012

I have a lot of C# Code that I have to write in C++. I don't have much experience in C++.

I am using **Visual Studio 2012** to build. The project is an Static Library in **C++ (not in C++/CLI)**.

In the C# code there is a class for which some static instances are created

**C#**

```
namespace MyNamespace
{
      public class MyClass
      {
          //Class Code

         static public MyClass Instance1 = new MyClass(/*parameters*/);
         static public MyClass Instance2 = new MyClass(/*other parameters*/);
```

I need to do something similar in C++, **so far I got**:

**C++**

```
namespace MyNamespace
{
    class MyClass
    {
        //Class Code

     }//end of class

    static MyClass& Instance1 = MyClass(/*parameters*/);
    static MyClass& Instance2 = MyClass(/*other parameters*/);

}//end of Namespace
```

However, from what I read this is not quite the same, by adding the word "static" what I am doing is that my Instance1 and Instance2 are only visible within the scope of the current file. Is this correct?

So I don't want a bunch of Instance1, i just want one in the entire program.
I read that instead of using **static**, I could use **extern**, which tells the compiler the definition of the variable is in another file, thus I would wind up with only one instance of Instance1 and Instance2 and not multiple ones.

**So I tried:**

**C++ MyClass.h**

```
extern MyClass& Instance1;
extern MyClass& Instance2;
```

**C++ MyClass.cpp**

```
MyClass& Instance1 = MyClass(/*parameters*/);
MyClass& Instance2 = MyClass(/*other parameters*/);
```

**This builds just fine, but when I try to run my tests, they throw an error:**

```
 Failed to set up the execution context to run the test
```

Before using **extern** my tests ran just fine, but when I add it they won't work. Which leads me to believe I am not declaring things properly, or maybe Visual Studio 2012 doesn't support properly some of this functionality?

Answer (score 4, accepted):

`static` has different meanings in C++ according to where it is used. When used with a variable declaration it means what you were thinking: no linkage for the variable, it is available just to the file in which it is declared or even, if it's a local variable, that there is just one copy of it (good way to declare local variables which are supposed to be static near where they are used).

In a class declaration though static means the same thing as in C# with the difference that you must have a source file which actually declares the static variable (or declare it as `static` inside a method), this because this `static` variable must be have the space reserved somewhere. This can be done in multiple ways, for example:

```
static MyClass& instance() {
  static MyClass realInstance;
  return realInstance;
}
```

In this way you can see both ways of using `static`: one is to tell that the `instance()` method is `static` (attached to the class namespace, not to a single instance) in the contained class, and one to declare a static variable that will have just one copy of itself even if it's a local variable.

Comment: One question, you do static MyClass realInstance, there is where i am supposed to initialize my istance no?

Comment: What if you create the instance in the cpp, but outside the Instance() method? Would it be the same?

Comment: It would be the same thing, yes

Answer (score 2):

No, `static` means what you want it to mean *when used to declare class members*.

When used to declare global, non-member variables, it has the "only within current file" meaning.

`static` is a very versatile word in C++.

But yes, your first attempt is the correct one (except for the  `&`. Remove that. You don't want to store a reference to an object that immediately goes out of scope and gets destroyed. You want to store the object itself)

Comment: I am confused, you are saying that by having & I am actualy saving a static reference? So the object itself might be destroyed?

Comment: Yes, you are specifying that the static member should be a reference

Comment: From what I can understand, your answer seems to contradict the other answers, they say that I will wind up with several instances of Instance1 in the way I have my code, and I should make a function that returns my Instance1, don't you agree?

Answer (score 1):

In C++, code is divided by units called "units of translation". One unit of tranlation is, simply speaking, one `.cpp` file.

A "static" variable is one that exists in the unit of translation it is defined. So, if you have:

**Static.h**

```
static int myStatic = 0;
```

**Static1.cpp**

```
#include "Static.h"
```

**Static2.cpp**

```
#include "Static.h"
```

you will actually have 2 copies of static variable myStatic, one per each unit of translation. As a rule of thumb, never declare static variables in headers, unless it's a template class (I actually wonder why it is still not a warning). .h files are not actually compiled, they are pieces of code *included* into the cpp file (hence the keyword `#include`)

To do it "canonically", you need to do it like this:

**Static.h**

```
class MyClass {
public:
    static MyClass& GetInstance1();
    static MyClass& GetInstance2(); // static method means just same as in C#
// Other stuff
}
```

**Static.cpp**

```
#include "Static.h"

static MyClass instance1(/* parameters */);
static MyClass instance2(/* other parameters */);

MyClass& MyClass::GetInstance1() {return instance1;}
MyClass& MyClass::GetInstance2() {return instance2;}
```

A little verbose, but more flexible in some cases compared to C#.

Usage:

**SomeOtherFile.cpp**

```
#include "Static.h"

MyClass::GetInstance1().DoSomeAction();
```

I believe, your tests will run correctly after that.

Comment: So I shouldn't declare static things directly in the namespace? In my code I am declaring them in the .h file but in the namespace not the Class itself

Comment: The problem is not about namespaces, but in translation units. Make sure you have `static something` declared in the `.cpp` file, and the methods to access it in `.h` file. If you declare them in your `.h`, every `.cpp` where you `#include` your header will have own copy of your "not-so-static" variable.

Answer (score 0):

Static variables cannot be "seen" outside file in which you declared them. But if you need to use that variable in other file, you can write a static function in a class which return that static variable.