# How to wrapp static Instance?

Tags: c++-cli

I am using Visual Studio 2012, working with a C++ Native Library and Creating a C++/CLI wrapper for it.

Following [this](https://stackoverflow.com/a/20122569/752842) answer I have a class with functions that return static instances in C++ like this:

**MyCppClass.h**

```
class MyCppClass
{
private:
    MyCppClass(std::string name);
    ~MyCppClass(void);

public:                 

    static const MyCppClass& MyInstance1();
    static const MyCppClass& MyInstance2();     
};
```

**Instance methods in my MyCppClass.cpp**

```
#include "MyCppClass.h"

const MyCppClass& MyCppClass::MyInstance1()
{       
    static const MyCppClass instance1("Instance1Name");
    return instance1;
}

const MyCppClass& MyCppClass::MyInstance2()
{       
    static const MyCppClass instance2("Instance2Name");
    return instance2;
}
```

My C++ code is working fine. Now I am building a C++/CLI wrapper so all this functionality can be accessed from C#.

I am building all my wrappers following this fashion:
My Managed class holds a pointer to the unmanaged class, I create the instance when appropriate, and destroy it on the destructor. I marshal the parameters that come from C# to C++ and use the logic in C++.

I want to use the static instance for MyCppWrapper in C# like I am using them in C++. And I want the C++/CLI hold a reference to the Static Instance of C++.

**How do you accomplish this?**

I tried difference things but most wouldn't build, finally I got this:

**MyWrapper.h**

```
public ref class  MyWrapper
{
private:
    const MyCppClass * internalInstance;
    MyWrapper(const MyCppClass * internalInstance);
    ~MyWrapper(void);

static const MyWrapper^ instance1;
public:

    property static const MyWrapper^ Instance1
    {
        const MyWrapper^ get();
    }
```

**MyWrapper.cpp**

```
MyWrapper::~MyWrapper()
{
    //Should I delete the pointer??
}

MyWrapper::MyWrapper(const MyCppClass* instance)
{
    internalInstance= instance;
}

const MyWrapper^ MyWrapper::Instance1::get()
{
    if(instance1== nullptr)
    {
        instance1 = gcnew MyWrapper(&(MyCppClass::Instance1()));
    }

    return instance1;
}
```

Is this the correct way to do what I am trying to do?

What should I do with the **const MyCppClass * internalInstance;** pointer, I don't think I can't destroy it because it was not created with new and I could mess things up.

Comment: You don't own the object, you just have a pointer to it. So you should not need to to anything to it. In other words: if you `new`, `delete`.

Comment: Isn't there a method to destroy the instance in your base library ? You should implement IDisposable and call it in Dispose().

Comment: If the instances are static objects, you don't need to destroy them. They're supposed to be destroyed at program termination, like global variables (in practice, I'm not sure they are, though).

Comment: @crashmstr yes I have read that every new requires a delete, but this caes was confusing for me. Does the rest of the implementation seem fine?

Comment: @Aybe I am not sure what do you mean with the IDisposable. You mean I should implement it here to dispose the pointer? But as it is static, like crashmstr and Medinoc said, I can't delete it.

Comment: It is recommended to implement the following pattern using IDisposable : http://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/fs2xkftw(v=vs.110).aspx but in your case as your instance is static you won't need it.

Comment: @Aybe from my understanding that pattern indicates that you have to call the Dispose method when you are done with the object, no? I my case I can't be sure people using my Wrapping dll will do that, most likely they won't. Do you think it would still be worth it to implement IDisposable? I assume that if you don't use the normal life cycle of the objects would work anyway, no?

Comment: Yes and I forgot to mention that it works in conjunction with `using` : http://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/yh598w02.aspx. This pattern is great because it ensures disposition of resources even when an exception occurs and you gain in code clarity as well. Now in C# a static class cannot be disposed which makes me believe it's not a good pattern to follow (to create a static instance) but this is my opinion and C++ is way more flexible. Either way will get the job done in the end. Personally I wouldn't go static as it's the pattern I've seen the most in libraries I've used.

Comment: Here is an example of the pattern implemented against a native DLL I needed to use in C# and with the same usual ease : http://pastebin.com/xTAmhViQ. There's a factory method and Dispose pattern. If you want to comply to .NET style then do it this way, otherwise as I said just make the thing work and use it as-is.

Comment: @Aybe I understand about the IDisposable, and it seems a good practice, I will be considering adding it to all my wrappers, depends on the time I have left. But In the case of this Static class, I want to make this instance static, and it has a reference to a static instance in C++, it is sort of a "convenience" class. It would be far too troublesome, and it could even lead to confusion not to have them Static. And I wanted to make sure I was using Static properly in both contexts (C++ and C++/CLI)